# Add a dot in Calculator Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dot

I've tried implementing the dot or "point" in calculator I'm programming the windows 7 calculator as a reference to my calcu.

I've tried this in my code:

```
@IBAction func btnDot(sender: AnyObject) {
    if(lblResult.text!.characters.count == 0) {
        lblResult.text = "0."
    }
    else {
        if(Float(lblResult.text!.lowercaseString.characters.contains(".")) == -1) {
            lblResult.text = lblResult.text! + "."
        }
    }
    lblResult.text = lblResult.text
}
```

but the function btnDot doesn't seem to work. What seems to be the problem here?

> **Note:** The lblResult.text is the Id of my UILabel for the display of results

Comment: *"doesn't seem to work"* is a useless problem description. What is the input, the actual result and the expected result? – And split your expression in smaller separate statements to isolate the problem (in other words: learn how to debug).

Comment: *Hint:* `Float(someText.contains(".")) == -1` will never be true. Where did you find that?

Comment: And this line:   lblResult.text = lblResult.text    does nothing

Comment: As I said I'm new to swift programming, I've only convert the code above base on my javascript code. It's my first attempt though, don't be strong @Martin R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
if (lblResult.text?.characters.count == 0){
    lblResult.text = "0."
}
else{
    if lblResult.text!.rangeOfString(".") == nil{
       lblResult.text = lblResult.text! + "."
    }
}
```

If you want help you with your code you'll need to provide more info about the problem, now I just could give you a working example.

Comment: I agree, but as I have updated the answer the user did not provide much information. @rmaddy

Comment: Sorry about that, next time I'll improve my question. This code works, I'm just new to the syntax of xcode here. That's why I'm having a hard time learning its syntax.